# Read XML file with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri

I currently have an XML file that is reading correctly except for one part. It is an item list and sometimes one item has multiple barcodes. In my code it only pulls out the first. How can I iterate over multiple barcodes. Please see code below:

```
def self.pos_import(xml)
  Plu.transaction do
    Plu.delete_all
    xml.xpath('//Item').each do |xml|
      plu_import = Plu.new
      plu_import.update_pointer = xml.at('Update_Type').content
      plu_import.plu = xml.at('item_no').content
      plu_import.dept = xml.at('department').content
      plu_import.item_description = xml.at('item_description').content
      plu_import.price = xml.at('item_price').content
      plu_import.barcodes = xml.at('UPC_Code').content
      plu_import.sync_date = Time.now
      plu_import.save!
    end
  end
```

My test XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="no"?>
<items>
  <Item>
    <Update_Type>2</Update_Type>
    <item_no>0000005110</item_no>
    <department>2</department>
    <item_description>DISC-ALCOHOL PAD STERIL 200CT</item_description>
    <item_price>7.99</item_price>
    <taxable>No</taxable>
    <Barcode>
        <UPC_Code>0000005110</UPC_Code>
        <UPC_Code>1234567890</UPC_Code>
    </Barcode>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Any ideas how to pull both UPC_Code fields out and write them to my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the great tips. It definitely led me in the right direction. The way that I got it to work was just adding a period before the double //.

```
plu_import.barcodes = xml.xpath('.//UPC_Code').map(&:content)
```

Answer (score 1):

`.at` will always return a single element.  To get an array of elements use `xpath` like you do to get the list of Item elements.

```
plu_import.barcodes = xml.xpath('//UPC_Code').map(&:content)
```

Comment: This still is only putting the first UPC_Code into the field. It doesn't put both UPC_Code fields in there.

Comment: There was an error in the xpath statement. It should have two `//` to find all of the UPC_code tags.

Comment: I noticed that and changed it in my code with no luck. Still just the first UPC_Code.

plu_import.barcodes = xml.xpath('//UPC_Code').map(&:content)

Comment: The method to find multiple nodes that is the corollary of `at`, is `search`. Both `at` and `search` will take either a CSS or XPath selector. The CSS/XPath specific versions are `at_css`, `at_xpath`, or `css` and `xpath`. These are all documented in the [Nokogiri::XML::Node](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html) documentation.

Comment: @Infused: you're right, I misread the XML, thinking UPC_Code was a child of Item